# Linking a JavaScript file to HTML file not working by any means

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I've tried all the posibilities as described in previous similar cases and still no results.

I'm adding the link tags at the end of the  of the HTML and I am calling the folder where the file is placed but still nothing.

```
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../pages/counter.js"></script>
```

Folder structure:

[image: screenshot of the place of the folder where the js file is]

Comment: Please share the actual HTML code, not what's displayed on the page. Thanks

Comment: With the screen you shared I don't properly understand the hierarchy but have you tried `src="./pages/counter.js"`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear for me where is the js file. But you should try the same folder:
"./pages/counter.js"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `pages` has the same hierarchy level as index.html, so the path getting used is incorrect.

Try using the following path:

```
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./pages/counter.js"></script>
```

Let me know in case of issues

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your index file is in same directory as of pages. So try